# How to send data to front end js of a server from another server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have two routes like this in an *express js app*.

```
router.get('/route', function (req, res) {
   res.redirect('/newRoute');
});


router.get('/newRoute', function (req, res) {
   var data = someCalculation();
});
```

I make a call from another *application server's* `index.html` front end js code.

```
window.open('http://nodeserver/route');
```

Is there any way that I could get `data` in the front end of the *application server* (`index` file).

I have tried using `localstorage`, but since both servers are different url I couldn't make it happen.

Comment: just make an ajax call

Answer (score 0):

First you have to publish your route file in node server.Then in another server where you call a route you have to call it like **REST API** url like this

```
107.65.32.1:8080/route
```